# Shopify buy buttons not showing on mobile

Tags: javascript, embed, shopify

I have some shopify Buy buttons on my website. They show fine on desktop browsers - the site is responsive and the buttons show on all viewport queries on desktop browsers.

When viewing the site on mobile I get no buy buttons. I thought it may be a cross-origin issue so I hosted the shopify javascript files locally and I get the same behaviour.

I have tried all the different versions of the buy now button and I get the same behaviour.

Is there a reason I can't see buy buttons on mobile? Site is www.redlamp.com.au/myriad/shopify2.html

Comment: Did you fix it? I tried on a mobile device and the buy buttons are there.

Comment: Nope, not fixed yet, what device and browser are you using? Buttons still not showing on Android using chrome browser. I have looked at other sites using the same tech and they aren't showing either.

Comment: I have used my iPhone 6 Plus running the latest iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit - I had extended the Object with my own rudimentary add/remove class functions. Removing the following code fixed the problem:

```
Object.prototype.addClass = function(clas) {        

    if (this.classList)
        this.classList.add(clas);
    else
        this.className += ' ' + clas;

}

Object.prototype.remClass = function(clas) {        

    if (this.classList)
        this.classList.remove(clas);
    else
        return;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the shopify code `buy-button-storefront.min.js:7 TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Invalid value(…)`

It seems that [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) is not available on your Android device [see more info here](http://caniuse.com/#search=fetch).

Try to add a polyfill like [that one](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/fetch) before running the Shopify code.

or maybe there is really an error on their sides. You can address the problem on [their GitHub repo](https://github.com/Shopify/buy-button-js/issues)

Comment: Thanks, the polyfil didn't work though. I have raised an issue on their github. The weird thing is that it works fine on chrome desktop but if I open developer tools and go into responsive mode then refresh the page I get that error. It's something specifically with the mobile viewport...

Comment: Glad I helped. Let me know.